# Spring Boot @Scheduled does not work for DB transactions

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a scheduled job which will delete all records in DB and insert fresh data for every 10 mins. This works well if i call the service manually by creating one web service. However the scheduled job unable to delete and insert. I am using JPA for delete all records and save. I have maintained @Transactional annotation too, but no luck so far. Any thoughts?

```
@Service
public class ScheduledService {

    @Autowired
    MainService mainService;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay=100000, initialDelay=10000)
    public void updateAllScreensScheduled() {
        mainService.updateAllScreens();
    }
}
```

My MainService.java

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void updateAllScreens() {
   tSerScheduleJpaRepository.deleteAll();   // delete all schedule data
   List<ScheduleData> scArr = getFreshData();   // get all schedule data            
   List<TSerScheduleEntity> list= new ArrayList<>();
            for (ScheduleData scheduleData : scArr) {
                TSerScheduleEntity entity = new TSerScheduleEntity();
                entity.setRtNm(scheduleData.getRtNm());
                list.add(entity);
            }
            tSerScheduleJpaRepository.save(list);   // save schedule data
        }
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: No errors, everything seems good..but data is not saved in DB.

Comment: Is the method `updateAllScreensScheduled()` getting called? Do you have `@EnableScheduling` somewhere?

Comment: Yes, tested in debug mode and everything is executed. I kept @EnableScheduling in spring boot main class.

Comment: Have you tried without `propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` in your `@Transaction` ?

Comment: Yes, initial it was without any propagation. Later I just added to make sure the transaction is available.

Answer (score 0):

I got such issue solved with creating a method annotated with `@Async` with the body `mainService.updateAllScreens();` that is called from `updateAllScreens()`

So `updateAllScreensScheduled()` would look like just a call of the async method

P.S. don't forget to add `@EnableAsync` to the configuration